# Impacts of running "./CA newca" command in /etc/pki/tls/misc/ when CA already exists

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, centos

After accidentally running "./CA newca" from /etc/pki/tls/misc, I noticed a few files getting updated in /etc/pki/CA, and possibly more.  But there weren't any prompts when running the command like there normally is.  I meant to run the "./CA -sign" command instead to add to the current CA.  Will this have any consequences?  I've created a new CA in the past, and I've always had to remove these files, yet none of these got changed, but that doesn't necessarily mean "other" files don't get updated when creating a new CA.

```
# rm –f /etc/pki/CA/*
# rm –f /etc/pki/CA/private/cakey.pem
# rm –f /etc/pki/CA/newcerts/*
# rm –f /etc/pki/tls/misc/newreq.pem
# rm –f /etc/pki/tls/misc/newcert.pem
```

Here are the files that got updated:

```
/etc/pki/CA/serial
/etc/pki/CA/index.txt.old
/etc/pki/CA/index.attr
/etc/pki/CA/index.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this, and the answer is "No"

I successfully tested Tomcat to Tomcat connectivity with SSL communication for an existing self-signed certificate (signed by this CA) and a new self-signed certificate (signed by this CA) added to the index.txt file. All entries that were marked as "R" don't work, and all entries that were marked as "V" still work. This was after taking no action after I ran that bad command by mistake except for signing that new self-signed certificate for a new server.

Comment: MacGyver - I have edited your comment into the post, as that is where it should be, not in a comment thread.